# Error using express-session with express

Tags: node.js, express

**Problem:**
When i try to use session = require("express-session"), it gives error to install express-session but i am already installed it using npm install express-session. The error i am receiving is :

```
vishal@rocker:~/clg/project1/node_modules/express$ nodejs server.js

Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/vishal/clg/project1/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vishal/clg/project1/node_modules/express/server.js:17:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

**Now after installing express-session my directory structure is**

```
node_modules
   express
       server.js // file where i am using it

   express-session
```

Server.js

```
var express = require("express"),
http = require("http"),
session = require("express-session"),
login = require("./server/login"),
app;
app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

// set up a static file directory to use for default routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/client"));

// set up express session to create session when user successfully        login
app.use(express.session({secret: '123456'}));

// set up our routes
// for user login
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {

var result = login.validate(req,res);
if(result){
    req.session.username="admin";
    res.send("successfully logged in");
}
else{

    res.append("error","Authentication Failed");
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/client/index.html");
}

});

app.get("/goodbye", function (req, res) {
res.send("Goodbye World!");
});
```

My new package.json

```
{
"name": "askr",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Class project for 473",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "BSD-2-Clause",
"dependencies": {
"express-session": "~1.10.3",
"express": "~4.12.2"
}
}
```

Comment: It may help if you show us more of your code.

Comment: uhm... are you editing server.js, inside of your node_modules folder?

Comment: yes I am editing server.js inside node_modules>express folder

Comment: var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    session = require("express-session"),
    login = require("./server/login"),
    app;

// Create our Express-powered HTTP server
// and have it listen on port 3000
app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

Comment: That belongs in your question, where we can read it. There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28889288/edit) button below the question.

Comment: In package.json express-session is also mentioned in dependencies.  "express-session": "~1.10.3",

Comment: Do not edit files inside of your node_modules folder. Your code goes outside of that folder.

Comment: Can you please provide me any tutorial to setup new project

Comment: the depreciation notice you are getting is due to this line: `app.use(express.session({secret: '123456'}));` you are using `express.session` instead of `session`.

Comment: The install error you are getting is due to running your code in the wrong place, simply move your server.js to outside the node_modules folder. No, i don't have any tutorials to share.

Comment: I tried with moving code to outside node_module folder. But still it gives same error. do i need to have package.json with server.js?

Comment: yes, but it should have it's own package.json, not the one from the express folder. I suggest deleting your node_modules folder and starting over. delete folder, then run `npm init` to create your package.json, then `npm install --save express express-session` to install `express` and `express session` and automatically save it to the package.json.

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: Which error? you mention two.

Comment: Then you still haven't made the change i suggested before. *"the depreciation notice you are getting is due to this line: `app.use(express.session({secret: '123456'}));` you are using `express.session` instead of `session`."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**express.session** is depreciated use **session** directly. If you are getting this error while using some other module make sure you have mentioned method name correctly.